# JQuery - Insert bottom "cap" – matching background color of caption – after each table

Tags: jquery

I have a site with many, many tables. These tables are color-coded (with dozens of colors that vary across the site), each with a caption styled as a label at the top.

In order to avoid the nightmare of touching every table, I'd like to use JQuery to automatically add a nice matching bottom for all these tables, taking the background color of the caption, applying it to this bottom, and inserting it after each table site-wide. Sort of like adding a matching pair of shoes to go with a hat (probably a poor fashion choice, I know, but bear with me).

The following is the closest I've gotten, but it inserts *all* the bottoms on *all* the tables on the page – such that if I have three tables on a page, each has three bottoms.

```
$( 'table caption' ).each( function() {
  var tableBottomColor =  $( this ).css( 'backgroundColor' );
  //add colored footers to all tables
  $( '<div class="tablebottom" style="background-color:' + tableBottomColor+'"></div>' ).insertAfter( 'table' );
});
```

I tried adding a ('table').each function around the insertAfter statement, but then I had 9 bottoms on each table.

[Here's a quick fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/halfacre/p8agb7mo/13/)

How can I add one bottom to each table with a background color that matches that of its respective caption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out after stepping away for a bit. Forests/trees and what have you.

Instead of applying `insertAfter` to `'table'`, which would mean every instance of a table with every table bottom, I needed to apply it only to *this* table (`$(this)`, naturally).

```
  $( 'table caption' ).each( function() {
      var tableBottomColor =  $( this ).css( 'backgroundColor' );
      //add colored footers to all tables

    $('<div class="tablebottom" style="background-color:' + tableBottomColor+'"></div>').insertAfter($(this).parent());

    });
```

[Here's a fiddle with the solution applied.](https://jsfiddle.net/halfacre/y00Lngng/13/)